# ApachePOIでExcelシートに画像を挿入すると画像の縦横比が崩れる

Tags: excel, apache-poi

**Version情報**
POI 3.16
Excel 2013

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/apache-poi-excel-insert-image.html

上記リンク先のサンプルコードを実行し、生成された.xlsxファイルを開くと、縦横比が崩れています。図の書式設定で確認すると、挿入した画像の解像度に応じて以下の値になっていました。

元画像解像度: 400x176
高さの調整: 93%
幅の調整: 125%

元画像解像度: 400x32
高さの調整: 95%
幅の調整: 128%

http://grum.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/06/13/020000
規定のフォント設定も影響するかもという情報もあったので試してみましたが、効果はありませんでした。

この質問内容とも関連しそうかなと思っています。
[C# epplusライブラリでエクセルに挿入した画像の表示比率が崩れるので、直したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38046/c-epplus%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A8%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB%E6%8C%BF%E5%85%A5%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%81%AE%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E6%AF%94%E7%8E%87%E3%81%8C%E5%B4%A9%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7-%E7%9B%B4%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)